# Find $\lim_{x\to 0} x^{-2/3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$\lim_{x\to 0} x^{-2/3}$$

As i know this will goes to infinity as $x$ approaches $0$. How to show it by some proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $M>0$. Then, $|x|=|x-0|< M^{-3/2} \implies |x^{-2/3}| > M$. Thus, $\lim_{x \to 0} x^{-2/3} = \infty$. (This is actually the full $(\epsilon,\delta)$ proof).

Answer (score 0):

You are right - it does go to infinity.  Draw the graph - you see that the two sided limit does not exist.

Comment: I know this fact...I need some proof for that

Comment: The graph works. Not all limits converge. As a matter of fact, take $ y=x^{-1} $. Then take the limit as y goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f$ converges to some $L$ at zero. This means that for any sequence $(a_n)$ which converges to zero, then $f(a_n)$ converges to $L$. Do you know this equivalence (you can translate $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition to sequences)?

Now let $(1/n^{3/2})$ be such a sequence which converges to zero (why?), so $(f(1/n^{3/2}))$ converges to $L$. But then $f(1/n^{3/2})= n$, which diverges. Contradiction.